# automatic external sdcard mounting does not occur in the Android Jelly bean

Tags: sd-card, mount

I have a Genesis 7320 tablet with Android 4.2.1 and with root () via kingo) and 1 gig of ram.
I have a 16gb microsd. I installed external_2_internal.apk, which swaps the internal memory for
of the microsd card, but it didn't work. I installed from several tutorials I found
on the Internet. I left pressing several options. I thought I would solve the ram problem with 1 gb. I ended up uninstalling the application. After that, the tablet stopped automatically mounting the microsd. I give up and you go back to using link2sd, to solve the memory problem, but I need you to the assembly of the microsd is automatic again. Can someone help me?

Comment: solved! The problem was in the sdcard.